# IP match using regular expression in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I need some help in fixing my script for Validating IP Address.

**My program:-**

import re

ip_add = raw_input("Enter IP address to Validate : ")

valid_ip = re.search('^[1-255]+.[0-255]+.[0-255]+.[0-254]+$', ip_add)

if valid_ip:

```
print ip_add, " is valid"
```

else:

```
print ip_add, " is not valid"
```

---

**output**
Enter IP address to Validate : 1.1.1.254
1.1.1.254  is valid

**But it should not match with 1.1.1.255 as last is [0-254]+$**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After incorporating all the changes.
My program to Validate IP is given below :-

```
import re

ip_add = raw_input("Enter IP address to Validate : ")
ip_match = re.search(r'^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)$', ip_add)

if ip_match:
    a,b,c,d = ip_match.groups()
    ip_valid = 1 <= int(a) <= 255 and 1 <= int(b) <= 255 and 1 <= int(c) <= 255 and 1 <= int(d) <= 254
    if ip_valid:
        print ip_add, " is valid IP"
    else:
        print ip_add, " is not valid IP"
else:
    print ip_add, " not valid IP "
```

Answer (score 0):

The [1-255]+.[0-255]+.[0-255]+.[0-254] regex accepts the IP 1.1.1.25 and the +$ accepts the second '5' of 255.

Maybe there is a simpler solution for the IP regex problem but I suggest to use this one:

```
^(([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.)(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){2}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-4])$
```

Comment: Thanks @AndreyF for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As regular expressions work character by character it is IMHO impossible or at least very difficult to match a specific numeric range. I would instead recommend a two step validation that checks the allowed ranges after the regex matching.

```
ip_raw = raw_input("Enter IP address to Validate : ")
ip_match = re.match('^(d+).(d+).(d+).(d+)$', ip_raw)
if ip_match:
  a,b,c,d = re.groups()
  ip_valid = 1 <= a <= 255 and 1 <= b <= 255 and 1 <= c <= 255 and 1 <= d <= 254
```

Comment: Thanks @PeterE for new approach.